# Check if the focus is on the address bar or on the window and get corresponding selected text?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to get the current selected text on a tab.

I'm able to get it using `window.getSelection().toString();` but the problem is when the selected text is the address of the current tab.

`window.getSelection()` does not seem to detect that the text in the address bar is selected. Is there any way to detect that ?

Comment: Can't do. The address bar is not part of DOM so you can't use DOM methods to read its selection. Unfortunately there is also no dedicated API for that.

Comment: The `window.getSelection().toString(); ` will get you selected text in Dom. In case of null/empty result you can get the tabUrl using chrome API.